# How to Keep Syntax Coloring in Eclipse PHP after Restarting?

Tags: eclipse-pdt, theming

I use a clean installation of Eclipse PDT 2023-09 on Windows 10 with black theme. I modified the syntax coloring under Windows > Preferences > PHP > Editor > Syntax Coloring and save it. After restarting Eclipse, the colors settings were saved but not for "Bold" and "Italic" attributes. Are there any non-commercial plugin for theming that can fix that? It seems all the old plugins like "Eclipse Color Theme" don't work and not maintained any more.

Comment: Please make sure the bug has been reported [here](https://github.com/eclipse-pdt/pdt/issues), best with a pull request that fixes it. If it has been reported, it might contain a workaround. I doubt that another dark theme can be used as a workaround for this issue.